# Django session variable gets deleted when back button is clicked

Tags: python, django, session, request, session-variables

I am new to django. I want a page (lets say page X) to be accessible by the user only once (that too by a redirect). So what I did is used session variables to do this:

This is the view for the page from where I want to redirect the user to X -

```
def MainPageView(request):
    //Some code which doesn't use or modify session variables
    request.session['seen_status'] = False
    redirect ("url_of_X_%d" % some_int)
```

This is the view of X -

```
def Status(request,id):
    if request.session['seen_status'] == False:
           //some code which shows the page content
           request.session['seen_status] = True
           return render(page) //page contains a button 'A' to go to the next page
    else:
         //page to display if user has already seen the page.
```

This works fine if I go to X and refresh (that is, the else block gets executed). But, if the user goes to the next page by clicking the button 'A' and comes back using the back button of the browser, he can see the page again! I tried to debug this by using print statements, that is by printing request.session['seen_status'] but I get an error:

```
Not Found: /favicon.ico
```

Further, on clicking the back button, I don't get anything like:

```
[date_and_time] "GET url_of_page" somenumbers //which shows up when I go from MainPage to X
```

Any help on how to go about this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers store a cached version of each page, when the back button is clicked the cached version of the page is loaded.

You can add some javascript to your page to detect that a page was loaded from cache by the back button being clicked and reload the page

```
if(performance.navigation.type === 2) {
   // type is 2 when the back button is click
   location.reload(true);
}
```

This is deprecated however, the new (and uglier) version would be

```
if(performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type === "back_forward") {
   location.reload(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I understood that the browser cache was causing the problem....but apparently, even the javascript doesn't work when using the back button that is, even that is cached....so any way how to resolve that? @lain Shelvington